# What percentage of Marvel's Earth 616 has super-powers?

Tags: marvel, powers

Between all the mutants, aliens, mutates, super-soldiers, Inhumans etc, Earth 616 has a lot of super-powered people. But my question is how many?

I'm considering "super-powered" to mean:

- Capable of doing something impossible for a normal person to do.
- Their power is part of them (e.g., Iron-Man doesn't count)
- Their power isn't just being really skilled at something through normal training and practice (e.g., Punisher doesn't count)

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this please tell me why so I can improve the question?

Comment: 'percentage' of what... earth's population? Are you basically asking how many characters have 'super-powers' by your definitions in the entirety of the Earth-616 universe?

Comment: @dasmetzger No, I'm asking what percentage of the 616's earth's population has superpowers.

Comment: Our real earth exists in Earth-1218 in the Marvel Multiverse. The fact that our real world exists in the overall multiverse means one can assume that Earth-616 has roughly similar total world population, or 7.125 billion. Finding any significant percentage of people with super-powers among 7 billion would mean there are several million people with superpowers. 1% of 7 billion is 70 million, or twice the population of Tokyo, Earth's most populous city. It's quite an insane question, who's answer is probably in the .0005%, conservatively.

Comment: Writing as a comment because I'm too lazy to search for sources. Well, the magic factor is: when? Mutant population recently has been extremely variable, going from a little more than 30 million individuals in 2001, to about 14 millions after the Genosha massacre, then down and up again, and right now is about 200-300 people. Depending of the moment in time you choose, you may get very different results.

Answer (score 3):

The entirety of Marvel's characters (at least the interesting ones) have been listed [here](https://www.marvel.com/comics/characters)

Some [sources](https://www.quora.com/How-many-characters-are-in-the-Marvel-universe) say the total number of characters in Marvel is somewhere between 8,000-15,000 characters. Some of these might not have powers as per your definition of them, but I don't know why you have those limits (Iron Man if stronger than some mutants with his suit). Either way, there are many characters in his count who are in fact normal human beings. Also, some of those characters aren't even from Earth even though they do have powers. So just for argument's sake let's take the low number from those estimates of 8,000 people.

Now if we assume 616 has a population comparable to ours, say roughly 8 billion people. If we assume that 8000 of them have powers of some sorts that's about 1 person in every million, or about 0.0001% of the population. If you were instead to assume the highest number of 15,000 that would still only mean about 2 people for every million, so the difference isn't high.

That's really no so much is it? As an added bonus, this would also mean that a city like New York with about 8 million people, should only have about 8-16 powered individuals. 616's New York obviously has more, but that is likely an artifact of New York being a cultural hub in the 616 universe as it is in ours. After all, in our universe as well, New York is home to a large amount of actors, singers, artists, CEOs etc. That's far above the normal proportion of these people almost anywhere else.

Comment: It would seem to be a low-ball estimate to assume that super powered person on earth has managed to appear in print. New characters appear on a regular basis after all.